# WHMCS Pass variable to server provisioning module

Tags: whmcs

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a value from an order form to my server module.

For example on my order form a client can set a username, now I would like to pass the username to the server module to set the service up automatically.

Can one use placeholders in module setting fields to retrieve the data a client entered?

Any help is apprecitated.
Regards Stan

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [WHMCS Sample Provisioning Module](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-provisioning-module), in the [provisioningmodule_CreateAccount](https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-provisioning-module/blob/master/modules/servers/provisioningmodule/provisioningmodule.php#L152) function the username is passed in $params array as $params['username'].

The same goes for the password and other config options.